# Reversing graphics card driver change in Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia

Some idiot who looked back at me in the mirror a few minutes ago was following these instructions ([link](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-linux-mint-16/)) and apparently got the wrong NVIDIA drivers for his old laptop with a Quadro in it. Now, there's no display output. How do I reverse this?

Comment: Do you see a GRUB boot screen? If so, [this](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842) will tell you how to boot up with a default video driver so at least you'll be able to use your system and (hopefully) install the right driver.

Comment: @PM2Ring it does so only after a hard restart, sort of like Safe Mode in Windows. However, yes, it does, and it makes it so that I could reverse it. Thank you!